# use async to stop while loop from blocking the UX

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, while-loop, promise, async-await

For circumstances I cannot control I have a while loop that must be run on a frontend of an application with vanilla JS. The while loop is currently blocking the ui while it is being run for about 5 seconds so it is pretty noticeable. I have attempted to use an async function to no avail. the function can be boiled down to this. Any help would be appreciated.

```
let func = () => {
  let num=0;
  while(num<1000000){
   num = Math.random()*1000001
  }
  // do some stuff
}
```

Comment: look into setTimeout, and performing the loop in "chunks" instead of all at once

Comment: `while it is being run for about 5` - technically, that loop could run far far longer - that's randomness for you - does whatever calls func need to know when func is completed?

Comment: This is probably an XY problem. What exactly are the circumstances you can't control?

Comment: @JaromandaX no - everything else is fine, just trying to unblock the ui.

Comment: You can't run that loop in main thread and unlock the ui. Could try running it in a web workerr but using  promise based delay is  better option

Comment: by the way, you don't need to use `async` (and `await`) since the only asynchrony you would have is artificially introduced by you - therefore, as long as whatever calls `func` doesn't need any result, you just need to use setTimeout

Comment: @charlietfl by using promise based delay do you mean having a function that resolves a new promise in the while loop?

Comment: `promise based delay` would be overkill ... setTimeout is all you need

Comment: Still haven't answered what the higher level issue is you are trying to solve

Comment: @JaromandaX when would you use the setTimeout? in the while loop?

Comment: I wouldn't use it in the while loop - something like https://jsfiddle.net/Ljh6o7rz/

Comment: How about putting the while loop into a webWorker?

Answer (score 1):

You may use the [`Worker`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers) API to achieve real multi-thread tasks:

#### main.js

```js
const worker = new Worker('worker.js');

worker.onmessage = ({ data }) => {
  // the data is the calculated num
  console.log('result', data);

  // do some stuff
}

// This is where it's actually calling the loop function, and it's non-blocking
worker.postMessage({});
```

#### worker.js

```js
onmessage = function () {
  let num=0;
  while(num<1000000){
    num = Math.random()*1000001
  }
  postMessage(num);
}
```